# Mybatis enum select by id

Tags: java, enums, mybatis

My MyBatis code doesn't load the enum type (version: 3.4.4).

At MySQL database, I have a table with "cartype" field which is an INT(11) type.
In Java I created an ENUM for handling car types:

```
public enum CarType {
    SEDAN(1), LIMUSIN(2), WAGON(3);

    private int id;

    CarType(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Car mapper xml looks like this (contains no all data):

```
<select id="selectCar" parameterType="Car" resultMap="carResultMap">
SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE car_name="#{carName}";
</select>

<resultMap id="carResultMap" type="Car">
    <id property="id" column="car_name"/>
    <result property="carType" column="cartype"/>
</resultMap>
```

Finally my bean look like the followings:

```
public class Car {
    private Integer id;
    private CarType carType;
}
```

The bean contains getters and setters too.

When I try to get the Car in java, it throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.data.bean.CarType.1
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumTypeHandler.getNullableResult(EnumTypeHandler.java:49)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumTypeHandler.getNullableResult(EnumTypeHandler.java:26)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:66)
```

Comment: you could try building and linking here a minimal, complete example with -for example- h2 database (in memory) and maven so it can be easily ran. I also think it's the name of the enum (so, for example "SEDAN" that needs to be stored in the database, not the id)

Comment: Thanks it's work with the enum name instead of id. In select statement shoud use the UPPER() method for the name it's a little bit plus for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the enum name that needs to be stored in the database, not the id.

Take a look [here](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) . The default EnumTypeHandler expects a varchar:

> VARCHAR any string compatible type, as the code is stored (not index).

If you want or have to store the id you will need a custom [TypeHandler](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/type/TypeHandler.html). Something like this:

```
public class CarTypeTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<CarType> {

   public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int paramInt, CarType paramType, JdbcType jdbctype)
         throws SQLException {
      ps.setInt(paramInt, paramType.getId());
   }

   @Override
   public CarType getResult(ResultSet rs, String param) throws SQLException {
      return CarType.get(rs.getInt(param));
   }

   @Override
   public CarType getResult(CallableStatement cs, int col) throws SQLException {
      return CarType.get(cs.getInt(col));
   }
}
```

It will be convenient to have a lookup method in your enum too:

```
public static CarType get(int code) { 
   for(CarType s : values()) {
      if(s.id == code) return s;
   }
   return null;
}
```

You may also need to indicate the enum type explicitly in your mapper. Add a javaType parameter like so (I'm also including a sample type handler definition):

```
<result property="carType" 
  column="cartype" javaType="path.to.package.CarType" 
  typeHandler="path.to.package.CarTypeTypeHandler"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it's work with the enum name instead of id. In select statement shoud use the UPPER() method for the name it's a little bit plus for the solution.

Comment: How do I tell MyBatis to use the type handler for the enum using annotations for Spring Boot MyBatis?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#Handling_Enums

```
<!-- mybatis-config.xml -->
<typeHandlers>
  <typeHandler handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler"
    javaType="java.math.RoundingMode"/>
</typeHandlers>
```

For your case

```
<!-- mybatis-config.xml -->
<typeHandlers>
  <typeHandler handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler"
    javaType="org.data.bean.CarType"/>
</typeHandlers>
```